# Select an element without ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a little problem with changing the value of a `textbot`. The problem is that there is no `id` assigned to the `textbox`, so `getElementById` does not work, neither does `getElementsByName`.

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" name="custom_reason" size="50" maxlength="120" value="">
```

How would I change it's value?

Thank you.

Comment: There are other DOM methods that can get elements like [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)/[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Could you use jQuery?

Comment: `.getElementsByName("custom_reason")` returns an array you need an index to access one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the name instead:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("custom_reason")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and to include all the element’s features using [attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```js
document.querySelector('input.textbox' +
                       '[type="text"][name="custom_reason"]' +
                       '[size="50"][maxlength="120"]' +
                       '[value=""]').value = 'foo';
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textbox" name="custom_reason" size="50" maxlength="120" value="">
```

If the `name` is unique, you might want to use [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e16dwLp7/)):

```
document.getElementsByName('custom_reason')[0].value = 'foo';
```

Note there’s still more, like iterating all inputs or using jQuery.